# Android Widget button onClickPendingIntent not working after sleep

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-appwidget

I am learning to create Android widget based on tutorial from https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/

I have modified it so that the widget contains 2 intent, one for widget_button and another for widget_image. Both intent are working when the widget was newly added. However, after I left my phone go to sleep for longer period of time, only the intent for widget_image is working, whereas the intent for widget_button is not. If I open my app MainActivity, intent for widget_button will come back to work normally.

This is the widgetprovider class:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_image, pendingIntent);

        pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
}

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.example.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

}

This is the the receiver class:

```
public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int clickCount = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("com.example.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE")){
        updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
    }
}

private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());

    //REMEMBER TO ALWAYS REFRESH YOUR BUTTON CLICK LISTENERS!!!
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
}

private int getImageToSet() {

    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount == 1) {
        return R.drawable.image1 ;
    }
    if (clickCount == 2) {
        return R.drawable.image2 ;
    }
    if (clickCount == 3) {
        return R.drawable.image3 ;
    }
    clickCount = 0;
    return R.drawable.image4 ;
}
```

}

How to solve this?

Comment: Any solution for this issue?